# Dynamically changing requests based on previous response in SOAP UI NG Pro tool

Tags: arrays, groovy, soapui

Thanks in advance for the help. I am stuck in below scenario for a while. Since I am new to coding/programming, it is relatively tough for me to understand what's wrong in the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again. I have tried to ask the question in the recommended way. Apologies if you still have difficulties in understanding the question. Since this is the first post in Stack overflow, I will learn as you give me feedback. Thank you

**Scenario:**

1) I have a REST service which gives me back a response with multiple nodes.

eg:

```
[
      {
      "Namespace": "dbo",
      "ObjectName": "WorkOrder",
      "IsCustomQuery": false,
      "CustomQuery": null,
      "Name": "[dbo].[WorkOrder]",
      "Description": "",
      "Fields": []
   },
      {
      "Namespace": "dbo",
      "ObjectName": "sysdiagrams",
      "IsCustomQuery": false,
      "CustomQuery": null,
      "Name": "[dbo].[sysdiagrams]",
      "Description": "",
      "Fields": []
   },
      {
      "Namespace": "Maintenance",
      "ObjectName": "Configuration",
      "IsCustomQuery": false,
      "CustomQuery": null,
      "Name": "[Maintenance].[Configuration]",
      "Description": "",
      "Fields": []
   }
]
```

, and so on...

2. Now, I have to use each of this node as request and run another REST service(post). For example, If I have 3 nodes in step 1, I have to run 2nd REST service 3 times. One for each node.

My understanding was that, this could be achieved using set property(), get property() and FOR loop in groovy script.

Pseudocode:

1) Store each of the node in the response as an item in the array.

2) Find the number of nodes using sizeof()

3) Using the number of nodes as the max limit, use FOR loop with the POST request inside the loop using each item in an array as property.

Code used:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = context.expand( '${GET schema#Response}' ) /*GET schema is the GET request which returns the response with 12 nodes*/
def r = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
def n = r.size()
//log.info(r[1])
def i=0
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
testRunner.testCase.setValue("lists", r[i] as String)
def getLocalPropValue = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("lists")
log.info(getLocalPropValue) /* to verify that each item is retrieved*/
testRunner.runTestStepByName("REST Request") /*REST request is the POST service which should be run once for each of the nodes*/
}
```

Most common error message: - The error is in the 9th line.

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestCasePro.setValue() is applicable
>   for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values:
>   [lists, [CustomQuery:null, Description:, Fields:[],
>   IsCustomQuery:false, Name:[dbo].[WorkOrder], Namespace:dbo,
>   ObjectName:WorkOrder]] Possible solutions: setName(java.lang.String),
>   setName(java.lang.String), getName(), getClass() error at line: 10

Comment: What exact data you need to pass to request? do you need pass as it is or you need to change it?

Comment: @Rao Thanks for the reply. I need to pass the same data, one at a time to a REST service. For example, {
      "Namespace": "dbo",
      "ObjectName": "WorkOrder",
      "IsCustomQuery": false,
      "CustomQuery": null,
      "Name": "[dbo].[WorkOrder]",
      "Description": "",
      "Fields": []
   }, Above code would be my request for the next service. After this, next node should be made request content. This should be done for all the nodes present in the response.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. The issue us resolved now. - Manoj